# JBoss EAP 6.1 not showing JMX MBeans on JConsole

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, jmx, mbeans

I am deploying an application that uses Hibernate 4.2.0.Final and enables query cache (by setting property hibernate.cache.use_query_cache to "true" in persistence.xml) to JBoss EAP 6.1 Final.

After starting JBoss and deploying the application, when I open jboss-eap-6.1.0\bin\jconsole.bat, connect locally to the JBoss process and navigate to MBeans tab, I see nothing but a blank tab. I can't even see the basic MBeans that are usually registered (like jboss.* or java.lang.* MBeans).

I notice that just by changing the persistence.xml to set "hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" to "false" (or by removing the property, which has same effect in the end) everything works fine, i.e., I can see and manage MBeans from JConsole.

I don't know if it's a bug (if there is any) in Hibernate code or in JBoss code, but in any case I don´t know where to look at to fix this. Can anyone help me get both things working (Hibernate query cache and MBeans management through JConsole distributed in JBoss EAP installation)?

To help isolate and reproduce the problem, I built a simple EAR with minimum resources required to reproduce this issue and attached to a discussion opened in JBoss Forums, but so far I've not had any luck out there. If one is curious about it, the url is https://community.jboss.org/thread/233421

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is of any help, but:

When deplying the EAR, EAP throws a NumberFormatException on `Module "deployment.HibernateMBeanBug.ear.HibernateMBeanBug-persistence.jar:main" from Service Module Loader`, expecting "main" part to be a number. On JConsole access it throws NullPointerException on iterating the MBeans.

It is on this line:

```
doIterate(child, childAddress);
```

when detecting MBeans. child = null and childAddress=

```
[
    ("deployment" => "HibernateMBeanBug.ear"),
    ("subdeployment" => "HibernateMBeanBug-persistence.jar"),
    ("subsystem" => "jpa"),
    ("hibernate-persistence-unit" => "HibernateMBeanBug.ear/HibernateMBeanBug-persistence.jar#AnyPU"),
    ("entity-cache" => "org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache")
]
```

Then, when on the next iteration it asks for the kids of "child", it will hit a NPE.

Both exceptions are catchable with a debugger. Stack trace for the NPE is

```
Daemon System Thread [RMI TCP Connection(24)-192.168.11.2] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
    RootResourceIterator<T>.doIterate(Resource, PathAddress) line: 49   
    RootResourceIterator<T>.doIterate(Resource, PathAddress) line: 55   
    RootResourceIterator<T>.doIterate(Resource, PathAddress) line: 55   
    RootResourceIterator<T>.doIterate(Resource, PathAddress) line: 55   
    RootResourceIterator<T>.doIterate(Resource, PathAddress) line: 55   
    RootResourceIterator<T>.doIterate(Resource, PathAddress) line: 55   
    RootResourceIterator<T>.iterate() line: 39  
    ModelControllerMBeanHelper.queryNames(ObjectName, QueryExp) line: 144   
    ModelControllerMBeanServerPlugin.queryNames(ObjectName, QueryExp) line: 166 
    PluggableMBeanServerImpl.queryNames(ObjectName, QueryExp) line: 308 
    RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(int, Object[]) line: 1506 
    RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl, int, Object[]) line: 97 
    RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run() line: 1328  
    RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(int, Object[], Subject) line: 1420  
    RMIConnectionImpl.queryNames(ObjectName, MarshalledObject, Subject) line: 590   
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606  
    UnicastServerRef2(UnicastServerRef).dispatch(Remote, RemoteCall) line: 322  
    Transport$1.run() line: 177 
    Transport$1.run() line: 174 
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
    TCPTransport(Transport).serviceCall(RemoteCall) line: 173   
    TCPTransport.handleMessages(Connection, boolean) line: 556  
    TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0() line: 811 
    TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run() line: 670  
    ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1145  
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 615   
    Thread.run() line: 724
```

org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache is located at `jboss-eap-6.1\modules\system\layers\base\org\hibernate\main\hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar`, so just by updating that you might get rid of this problem.

At least the problem is fully reproducable, so I'd open an issue to [issues.jboss.org](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Update: testing updating the jar to 4.2.6.Final, didn't fix the issue.

Update2:

If you add into your persistence.xml second-level-cache:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
```

The problem goes away. Apparently, if you have query_cache enabled, the MBean iteration logic expects to find entity cache (second level cache) as well and will throw NPE if it is not defined. For a value "false" the problem persists, so it has to be enabled.

The above are just guesses though, I might be way off. However adding second-level cache seems to do the trick for a reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/180173

You need to set the system property org.apache.tomcat.util.ENABLE_MODELER to true to monitor these MBeans. This system property will cause JBoss to expose the MBeans "jboss.web:type=*".

You can add the system property to $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf on EAP 6 standalone mode like:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.ENABLE_MODELER=true"
```

Or the system property can also be defined in your JBoss EAP 6 configuration files (standalone(-*).xml or domain.xml, etc) like:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.ENABLE_MODELER" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

If you want to add the system property via management CLI:

```
/system-property=org.apache.tomcat.util.ENABLE_MODELER:add(value=true)
```

Note that setting the system property ENABLE_MODELER is broken on EAP 6.0.0 as discussed in JBoss fails to start with ENABLE_MODELER set to true. The fix for the issue is included in EAP 6.0.1 onward and this one off patch is available on customer portal for EAP 6.0.0.